# How to clone a Range Object in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am coding an Excel Macro in VBA using the Excel Visual Basic Editor.  I cannot figure out how to copy/clone a Range Object as opposed to creating a second reference to the same Object.

The MemberwiseClone() function does not seem to be available.  I thought it would be implemented for a built-in type.  Do I need to implement it myself?

In trying to figure this out, I might have gotten somewhat lost in the distinctions between VBA, Visual Basic, and Visual Basic .Net.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to copy/clone a Range Object rather than creating a second reference to the same Object, what distinction you make, what is the advantage? An object variable is only a pointer to part of memory.

Comment: @BobPhillips: I wanted to populate an array with the values from a Range and sort the array. There do not appear to be any native sorting functions for arrays though. I can write my own, but this just seemed weird. So I thought I would try to exploit the Range Object's sorting function but sorting a reference to the source Range causes the values in the Range on the source worksheet to be sorted. I can solve my initial problem but now I am just curious about all of the roadblocks I hit with my initial attempts -- like this one.

Comment: You can't create `Range` objects - they always refer to actual cells on actual sheets. You would have to copy the range's data to another range on a sheet and then sort that range. You can't do it purely in memory with a `Range` object.

Comment: You could just copy the original range, probably create a new worksheet and drop it there, use native Excel sorting on it, load the array, and delete the copied worksheet. It isn't cloning in memory, you can't do that as Rory says, but it is pretty straight-forward.

Comment: Thanks @Rory and BobPhillips. After much futzing around I had the impression that I would need to use temporary worksheets in lieu of memory. That just struck me as odd though. Why is the MemberwiseClone() function and, for that matter, the Array.Sort() function not available in the VBA editor? Do I need to add libraries? My understanding was that VBA was not limited to a subset of VB.Net

Comment: VBA predates .Net by a *long* way - the two are unrelated. VBA itself hasn't had much of an update in the last 15 year or so.

Answer (score 1):

While not necessarily the same thing, you can cover most use cases by creating a `Variant` object from the **values** of the range. This results in a variant array, which you can manipulate in memory to your heart's content.

```
Dim originalRange As Range, rangeCopy As Variant
' ...
rangeCopy = originalRange.Value
```

There are a few things to consider for this to work:

- The object has to be declared as a `Variant` - Do not declare a Variant array, or it will fail.
- You will obviously only get the values from the original range.
- The resulting Variant array is **always** 2-dimensional - even if only copying a single row or column (If range is only a single cell, the Variant is not an array). Address your values as `rangeCopy(row, column)`.
- When writing the array back into a Worksheet, be sure to do so into a Range that is the same size as the Variant array. Potentially, you need to adjust the cell number format as well.

Complete example:

```vb
Sub RangeCopyTest()

  Dim originalRange As Range, rangeCopy As Variant
  With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ListObjects(1)

    ' Range object
    Set originalRange = .ListRows(1).Range

    ' Make a copy (into an array) - values only
    rangeCopy = originalRange.Value

    ' Manipulate array
    ' Note: resulting array is ALWAYS 2-dimensional (row, column)
    rangeCopy(1, 1) = 2
    rangeCopy(1, 2) = "copy"
    rangeCopy(1, 3) = rangeCopy(1, 3) - 1
    rangeCopy(1, 4) = rangeCopy(1, 4) / 2

    ' Insert the copy back in
    .ListRows.Add
    .ListRows(2).Range.Value = rangeCopy

  End With
End Sub
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DVPp.png)

Answer (score -1):

I save my range to a range variable at module level: locally as Public or Private, or sometimes declaring it Global from another module.

As you can see Application.InputBox takes the Named Parameter Type. When Type:=8 It accepts a Range and Returns a Variant.

Ian

```
Option Explicit

Public Range1 As Range _
     , Range2 As Range
  
Public Sub SaveRangesDemo()

     ' Suggest you highlight "B2,D2,F2,H2:J2"
     
     Set Range1 = Application.InputBox("Select Range 1", "Range Highlighting", Type:=8)
     
     Cells(1, 1).Select
     
     ' Suggest you highlight "B4,B4:C5,B4:D6,B4:E7,B4:F8"
     
     Set Range2 = Application.InputBox("Select Range 2", "Range Highlighting", Type:=8)
     
     Cells(1, 1).Select
     
     Range1.Select
     
     MsgBox "Range 1 Highlighted", vbOKOnly, "Range Highlighting"

     Range2.Select
     
     MsgBox "Range 2 Highlighted", vbOKOnly, "Range Highlighting"

End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't clearly answer the question. Furthermore, since that question was asked nearly 8 years ago, this answer seems unmotivated.

Comment: Hi @Naemoor, this is not an answer to the question whitch speaks for "clone" while your code creates references to ranges and select them.