# Excel Class Object containing range looses data once source range in different workbook is closed

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a range into a class object i have written. This works as long as the range source object (workbook) is open. As soon as I close the range source object, my class looses the information it has for that object... other information in the class is maintained.

**Why does this happen? Shouldn't the range have been copied into the class object? Is there anyway to maintain the range information in the class with the source object closed?**

Here my example.
Copy this into a module:

```
Sub Test_Class()
Dim cls As Class1
Dim arr
Set cls = New Class1

Set cls.myrange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("E9:E12")
arr = cls.myrange 'Works
ws01.Range("G9:G12") = arr

Set cls = Nothing
Set cls = New Class1
Set cls.myrange = Workbooks("Other").Worksheets(1).Range("E9:E12")
Workbooks("Other").Close
arr = cls.myrange 'Fails on this line because object is lost
ws01.Range("G9:G12") = arr

End Sub
```

Copy this into a class module called Class1:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_objmyrange As Object

Public Property Get myrange() As Object
    Set myrange = m_objmyrange
End Property

Public Property Set myrange(ByVal objNewValue As Object)
    Set m_objmyrange = objNewValue
End Property
```

Comment: A range is an object so `Set cls.myrange = ` simply copies a reference to that object - i.e. `myrange` *is* `Range("E9:E12")`.  Use 
`Range.Copy` to get a copy into another existing range or iterate the range and store its values in a structure in your class.

Comment: I thought of iterating through the range and storing the values, but it's quite a bit of work, which if i can avoid i'd like to do. So would range.copy save it only while the source is open?

Comment: You can't store a Range on its own - it must exist attached to a sheet somewhere.  You can try using a Variant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33932000/how-to-clone-a-range-object-in-vba if your disinclined to copy (or copy the Range into a sheet in the workbook your code is running in).

Comment: Thank you! That essentially answers my question. It doesn't exist on its own and is really just a reference to a sheet. Makes sense that it doesn't exist when i close the source workbook then. If you put that as an answer i'll be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set cls.myrange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("E9:E12")`

This assigns a reference to the range the variable `myrange` rather than a copy.

As `myrange` points to the `Range` when the `Range` goes away so does your reference.

You can't store an instance of a `Range` on its own - it can only exist in relation to a `WorkSheet`, If you want a copy of the *data* in the range you can copy it  to a different sheet or get a 2D array [using a Variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33932000/how-to-clone-a-range-object-in-vba) that contains the data.